# Cannot display Chrome Add-On's icon

Tags: google-chrome, browser-addons, gui

I just installed **[Bulk URL Opener](https://melanto.com/apps/bulk-url-opener/)** on Chrome for Mac.

I am struggling to understand how to use the Extension, since it did not add an icon in the toolbar:

[image]

When I click on the three dots on the right:

[image]

These are the settings displayed in the corresponding extension page of Chrome:

[image]

I restarted Chrome, dug around and tried clicking or right-clicking around in the toolbar, but can't find how to make the installed add-on show in the toolbar.

Comment: Is it possible that the icon is just out of sight? Click the three dots to the far right (Chrome menu), does it show up there in the top row?

Comment: @Hexaholic see my edit

Comment: There is an app version and an extension version. You should check to see which one you have.

Comment: @Sonickyle27 I followed the same steps on my macbook and the icon appeared